# How to gracefully show an error screen when the session has expired in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have set the `config/session.php` to kill the session in half an hour. However, when I want to check if the session has expired (which it has), the following error screen pops up, when e.g. I click on my `Holidays` link:

```
in HolidayController.php line 46
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\empirehrms\app\Http\Controllers\HolidayController.php', '46', array('user' => null)) in HolidayController.php line 46
at HolidayController->create()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(HolidayController), 'create'), array()) in Controller.php line 80
at Controller->callAction('create', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(HolidayController), object(Route), 'create') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(HolidayController), object(Route), object(Request), 'create') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\HolidayController', 'create') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

I would like to show the user a page that tells them that they need to log in again.

Comment: Show appropriate code please.

Comment: You could try this: 
`if ( $e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException ) {
    return redirect()->route('login');
}` . If this does not work. then go through this link http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/session-timeout-for-logged-in-user

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin all the session code is the out of the box Laravel code. I have not changed the session settings, except the part where it says in `config/session.php` `lifetime' => 30,`

Comment: @Manish, where should I place this code?

Comment: You have to make `middleware` and add `constructor` where you want to run logout condition. I have found some link which will help you to make middleware [https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware] [http://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_middleware.htm]. 

if `if ( $e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException ) { return redirect()->route('login'); }` not working with **middleware** . then you can use second link [http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/session-timeout-for-logged-in-user] with **middleware**. this will definitely works for you.

Comment: @Manish I have tried that link before, it doesn't work

Comment: Did you use `middleware` ?

Comment: Yes, have used that